# Указатель на параметр в функции не работает

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

проблема в том что когда вызываю соответствующую функцию получаю ошибку об не инициализированной переменной t:

```
void addPassenger(BookTicket*t, vector<BookTicket>tickets){
    string name;
    string surname;
    string typeWagon;
    int numberWagon;
    int numberTrain;
    double price;
    cout << "Enter name";
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter surname";
    cin >> surname;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter type of wagon";
    cin >> typeWagon;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of wagon";
    cin >> numberWagon;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of train";
    cin >> numberTrain;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter price";
    cin >> price;
    cout << endl;
t=new BookTicket(name, surname, typeWagon, numberWagon, numberTrain, price);
tickets.push_back(*t);
}

    int main(){
    BookTicket *t;
    vector<BookTicket>tickets;
        BookTicket* t;
    addPassenger(*t,tickets)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Странно, если она у вас вообще компилируется - из-за объявления двух

```
BookTicket *t;
```

В таком объявлении нет инициализации, значение `t` не определено. Вы передаете его в функцию по значению - значит, функция получает мусор. Об этом компилятор и пытается предупредить.

Другое дело, что вашей функции этот параметр `t` *не нужен* - вы никак не используете его значение, используя его как обычную локальную переменную. С тем же успехом можно было бы написать функцию вида

```
void addPassenger(vector<BookTicket>tickets)
{
    BookTicket*t;
    string name;
    ...
```

Нетерпеливые, подождите ругаться, сейчас перейдем к главному.

А главное - что ваша функция не будет делать то, что вы от нее хотите. Потому что вы передаете в нее **копию** вектора `tickets`, так что вы добавляете новый элемент в копию, которая при выходе из функции уничтожается.

Поэтому на самом деле ваша функция должна иметь вид

```
void addPassenger(vector<BookTicket>& tickets)
{
    BookTicket*t;
    string name;
    ...
```

Но и это не все!

Вот тут

```
t=new BookTicket(name, surname, typeWagon, numberWagon, numberTrain, price);
tickets.push_back(*t);
```

вы создаете в динамической памяти экземпляр `BookTicket`, который передаете в `push_back`, где он *копируется*, а оригинал не уничтожаете. Получается утечка памяти. Лучше уж передавать сразу

```
tickets.push_back(BookTicket(name, surname, typeWagon, numberWagon, numberTrain, price));
```

и выбросить вашу переменную `BookTicket*t;` вообще!

Но еще лучше использовать функцию `emplace_back`, чтобы создавать объект прямо на месте, в векторе, без лишнего копирования:

```
tickets.emplace_back(BookTicket(name, surname, typeWagon, numberWagon, numberTrain, price));
```

Надеюсь, вы сможете теперь собрать все воедино?..

Comment: Да,конечно.Спасибо большое ,все доступно и понятно.

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - то слева от него есть птичка, нажав на которую, вы говорите тем самым, что вопрос полностью исчерпан...